# Add callback to infinite-scroll

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll

I am using [infinite scroll](https://infinite-scroll.com) so far everything is correct.

The elements that load the infiniti scroll have associated jquery functionalities that do not load when you move to the second page.

I've looked for information on adding callbacks but I'm unable to get it to work :(

according to the [documentation](https://infinite-scroll.com/events#append) it would be:

```
//  Triggered after item elements have been appended to the container.
$container.on( 'append.infiniteScroll', function( event, body, path, items, response ) {
  console.log(`Appended ${items.length} items on ${path}`);
});
```

The code to call Infinite scroll that I am using is:

```
$('.masonry-container').infiniteScroll({
  path: '.pagination__next',
  append: '.masonry-item',
  history: 'replace',
  status: '.page-load-status',
});
```

here you should call these simple functions:

```
// EDIT by comment @freedomn-m
$(function PIN() {
  $(document).on("click", ".showImage", function() {
    $('.pin-card').not('#pin' + $(this).attr('target')).hide();    
    $('#pin' + $(this).attr('target')).toggle();
  });

  $('.close').click(function() {
    $('.pin-card').not('#pin' + $(this).attr('target')).hide();
  });
});
```

what am I doing wrong?

ps.: thanks for the help

When loading new elements with infinite scroll I expected lazy load of images or other functions to be loaded so I could use them with the events.

Comment: Change your event binding to delegated event binding, eg `$(document).on("click", ".showImage", function() {...`

Comment: @freedomn-m It worked, thank you very much!

Comment: @freedomn-m   It hasn't worked for me for the following events(.pin-card and #pin' + $(this)). Do you know how I can solve it?  $(document).on("click", ".showImage", function() { $('.pin-card').not('#pin' + $(this).attr('target')).hide(); $('#pin' + $(this).attr('target')).toggle();